# Windows-7 booting gets stucked at startup screen

Tags: windows-7, boot

Pc gets stuck at "starting windows" screen. I also know what caused it-when making a new partition drive, i accidently changed the drive(in which windows 7 is installed) from primary to dynamic. Since then after restarting i got this problem. i tried in safe mode to boot up, but same thing persisits. i dont know what happens when a drive is changed to dynamic type.
Could anyone solve this problem.
Please dont ask to remove hardrive to restore data/ reinstalling os.
I dont have any backup or restore points earlier.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oww ... look ... you changed C:/ drive to another (ex D:/), when windows was started  (Is this possible)?

*First: Where you got your Windows copy ? Do you have it ? If no, then download pirate version and boot into it ... then start **Restore** and try to start it*(of course purchase the license if you don't have it yet if you might use it later).

I think your problem is in that some program or driver can't load from old disk mark (Like C:/ ... because it's not existing more) ...

My suggestion: **pick up (Download/Install) some Partition Manager ([Click](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php)) to USB disk (Boot from it) and change your new (System) drive name (mark) backward to C:/ ... Then restart comp.**

Hope this'll help.

Comment: I think its a pirated version( as it was not preinstalled when i bought my pc, my pc vendor would have installed a fake copy). so the cause is just because of the drive letter got changed?

Comment: Yup ... 60%. Try to change it backwards. Then post result.